# How to pass argument in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var Person = { 
    name: "jana",
    getName: function(callBack) {
        callBack();
        console.log("** "+this.name);
    }
}

var anotherPerson = { name: "prabu"}
```

I have 2 objects. I need "anotherPerson" to be bound with the `Person` object.  Also, I want to send parameter as a function.

I have tried below methods, but its not working

```
Person.getName.apply(anotherPerson, function(){})

Person.getName.apply(anotherPerson)(function(){})
```

Comment: [Apply accepts an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), so either pass an array, or use .call instead

Comment: Have you tried `Object.assign(Person, anotherPerson).getName(Object.assign(Person, anotherPerson).getName(alert))` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

Use `call` to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to your function, or `apply` to pass an array of arguments:

```js
var Person = {
  name: "jana",
  getName: function(callBack) {
    callBack();
    console.log("** " + this.name);
  }
}

var anotherPerson = {
  name: "prabu"
}

Person.getName.call(anotherPerson, function () {})

Person.getName.apply(anotherPerson, [function () {}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Object.assign` ? Like so

```js
var Person = {
  name: "jana",
  getName: function(callBack) {
    callBack();
    console.log("** " + this.name);
  }
}

var anotherPerson = {
  name: "prabu"
}
Object.assign(Person, anotherPerson).getName(alert)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow function and return the name parameter to assign value to getName.

```
  var Person = {
  name: "jana",
  getName: (obj) =>obj.name
   }

var anotherPerson = {
  name: "prabu"
}
Person.getName(anotherPerson);
console.log(Person);
```